# Подкиньте идейку

Tags: веб-программирование, javascript

Здравствуйте. Для курсовой я подготовил программу на управление объектом. Можете мне подкинуть какую нибудь идею, чтобы придать смысл данному алгоритму? Просто у меня что-то никаких идей нет... И еще вопрос, как сделать увеличение скорости интерактивное? (Жалкое подобие там есть, но не работает((( ). Заранее благодарю!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">#pole {
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    background: url(1.jpg);
    border: 5px solid #6b502e;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#obj {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
}</style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var left = false, right = false, top = false, bottom = false, s = false, n = 1;

function speed(){
    n = document.getElementById('speed').value
    return n;
}

function anim_right(right) {
    if (right){
    left = false; top = false; bottom = false;
    var oldLeft = parseInt(document.getElementById("obj").style.left), speed = n;
    document.getElementById("obj").style.left = oldLeft + speed + "px";

    }
    else return false;
}

function anim_bottom(bottom) {
    if (bottom){
    left = false; top = false; right = false;
    var oldTop = parseInt(document.getElementById("obj").style.top), speed = n;
    document.getElementById("obj").style.top = oldTop + speed + "px";
   } 
    else return false;
}

function anim_left(left) {
    if (left){
    right = false; top = false; bottom = false;
    var oldRight = parseInt(document.getElementById("obj").style.left), speed = n;
    document.getElementById("obj").style.left = oldRight - speed + "px";
    }
    else return false;
}

function anim_top(top) {
    if (top){
    right = false; left = false; bottom = false;
    var oldBottom = parseInt(document.getElementById("obj").style.top), speed = n;
    document.getElementById("obj").style.top = oldBottom - speed + "px";
    } ///вызов функции animation() через 100мс
    else return false;
}

function stop(s) {
    if (s){
    left = false; right = false; top = false; bottom = false;
    anim_top(top); anim_bottom(bottom); anim_right(right); anim_left(left);
}
    else return false;
}

function init(e){
switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 38 : {top = true; anim_top(top); setTimeout("anim_top(top)", 10); break; }
    case 39 : {right = true; anim_right(right); setTimeout("anim_right(right)", 10);             break;}
    case 40 : {bottom = true; anim_bottom(bottom);  setTimeout("anim_bottom(bottom)",    10); break;}
    case 37 : {left = true; anim_left(left); setTimeout("anim_left(left)", 10
        ); break;}
    case 32 : {s = true; stop(s); break;}
    default : return; break;
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body onkeydown="init(event)">
    <div id="pole">
        <div id="obj" style="position : relative; left : 100px; right : 100px; top :   100px; bottom : 100px; width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: black;"></div>
    </div>
    <p>Желаемый уровень сложности (скорость)</p>
    <input type="text" size="2" id="speed">
    <button onclick="speed">Установить</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Идейку? Напиши тоже самое по-русски. Ни фига не понятно

Comment: Что именно? Код?

Comment: тем более, с давних времен существует прекрасная библиотека jQuery. Для таких нубов как вы и я)))

Comment: Я прекрасно знаю что так jQuery и даже слегка с ней знаком. Но у меня курсовая работа по JavaScript который мы не проходили.

Comment: нет вопроса в данном вопросе....

Comment: Написано же. Подкиньте идейку для придания смысла алгоритму движения.

Comment: @relike, измените вопрос, чтобы было понятнее... только что я узнал от вас, что вас интересует алгоритм движения. Хорошо?

Comment: @relike, не следует ожидать, что все кинутся читать Ваш код и размышлять, что же делает (а что было задумано) эта программа.

@Deus, правильно написал Вам - описывайте по русски что программа должна делать в ответ на ввод пользователя.

Comment: почему бы просто не создать аквариум или футбольное поле, или самолетики или пинг-понг. Поработать с объектами чтобы они взаимодействовали между собой. Куча простых вещей уже присутсвует в сети. Думайте.

Comment: Она двигает объект по полю при помощью кнопок клавиатуры.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@relike](/users/16089/relike), а напишите "посадку на Луну".

Чуть переделайте, стрелки влево-вправо вращают модуль, а стрелки вверх-вниз увеличивают-уменьшают тягу двигателя.

Внизу нарисуйте поверхность с парой площадок, пригодных для посадки.

В начале модуль из верхнего угла по параболической траектории падает на поверхность. 
Все в соответствии с законом притяжения (ну, для простоты, пусть сила тяжести будет постоянна,
не зависит от высоты).

Нажимая на стрелки надо снизить скорость до нуля и выровнять модуль над одной из площадок.

В более сложном варианте можно ввести запас топлива и учитывать изменение массы модуля при его расходе.

Вот такая (совершенно не новая) идея.

Comment: @avp, у вас ваш первый компьютер не Спектрум, случайно, назывался? ))

Comment: @Deus, моей первой (тогда их называли ЭВМ) была Наири-2, размером с очень большой письменный стол (Спектрумов тогда еще не было) и "общаться" с ней можно было через перфоленту и электрическую пишущую машинку  Консул (насколько помню).

Comment: @avp, )) а у меня - калькулятор МК-61. 104 байта памяти. Я создавал игры: гонки и логические. Пишущая машинка у меня тоже была, электрическая,"Ромашка",по-моему.